# How to query or get other chaincode data in Hyperledger Composer?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

From a currently running business network/logic built from Composer, how can one query or get data from another business network (chaincode) using a composer app/javascript function?

Fabric's JIRA shows that at least querying within the same channel is available
https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1788

Answer (score 0):

Composer doesn't currently have any direct way to communicate with other business networks as yet. Business networks can emit events to external systems so you could create an intermediary client application to do something for now.
There is an issue tracking this requirement at
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/898

Answer (score 0):

I recently built some code to use with a hyperledger-composer (v0.13) app which monitors chaincode events so that the block information can be displayed as they are being created. The code is part of a new [Zero To Blockhain](https://github.com/rddill-IBM/ZeroToBlockchain) tutorial on blockchain. The code is in the queryBlockchain.js file in Chapter 5 & following. The folder structure to locate this file is:

```
Chapter 05
  ↳ controller
     ↳restapi
       router.js
        ↳features
           ↳composer
             autoLoad.js
             hlcAdmin.js
             queryBlockChain.js <=== You want this file for blockchain events
             Z2B_Services.js <=== and this file for socket communications with the browser
             Z2B_Utilities.js 
             ↳creds
```

and this uses credentials provided by the composer installation, which are stored  in the creds folder.

In reference to Jonathan's comment, the actual code referenced above accesses any business network, not just the one to which hyperledger composer is attached. At the fabric level, you would need access to a valid keyStore, the channel name, the peer request URL and the orderer URL for your target network. The code referenced code follows:

```
    var channel = {};
    var client = null;
    var wallet_path = path.join(__dirname, 'creds');
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        //
        // As of 9/28/2017 there is a known and unresolved bug in HyperLedger Fabric
        // https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/957
        // this requires that the file location for the wallet for Fabric version 1.0 be in the following location: 
        // {HOME}/.hfc-key-store
        // therefore the wallet location will be ignored and any private keys required to enroll a user in this process 
        // must be located in {HOME}/.hfc-key-store
        // this is currently managed for you in the installation exec by copying the private key for PeerAdmin to this location
        //
        console.log("Create a client and set the wallet location");
        // hfc = require('fabric-client');
        client = new hfc();
        return hfc.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: wallet_path })
        .then((wallet) => {
            client.setStateStore(wallet);
            // const config = require('../../../env.json');
            // which contains the following and is set in this
            // example to support the hyperledger fabric dev environment:
            // {
            //     "composer":
            //     {
            //         "connectionProfile": "hlfv1",
            //         "network": "zerotoblockchain-network",
            //         "adminID": "admin",
            //         "adminPW": "adminpw",
            //         "PeerAdmin": "PeerAdmin",
            //         "PeerPW": "randomString",
            //         "NS": "org.acme.Z2BTestNetwork"
            //     },
            //     "fabric":
            //     {
            //         "user": "queryUser",
            //         "eventURL": "grpc://localhost:7053",
            //         "channelName": "composerchannel",
            //         "keyValStore": ".composer-credentials/PeerAdmin",
            //         "wallet_store": "creds",
            //         "peer": "peer0.org1.example.com",
            //         "peerRequestURL": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            //         "peerEventURL": "grpc://localhost:7053",
            //         "ordererURL" : "grpc://localhost:7050",
            //         "caURL": "http://localhost:7054"
            //     }
            // }
            // 
            return client.getUserContext(config.composer.PeerAdmin, true);})
            .then((user) => {
                if (user === null || user === undefined || user.isEnrolled() === false) 
                    {console.error("User not defined, or not enrolled - error");}
                    channel = client.newChannel(config.fabric.channelName);
                    channel.addPeer(client.newPeer(config.fabric.peerRequestURL));
                    channel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer(config.fabric.ordererURL)); 
                 })
                .then(() => {
                    return channel.queryInfo()
                    .then((blockchainInfo) => {
                        if (blockchainInfo) {
                            res.send({"result": "success", "currentHash": blockchainInfo.currentBlockHash.toString("hex"), blockchain: blockchainInfo});
                        } else {
                            console.log('response_payload is null');
                            res.send({"result": "uncertain", "message": 'response_payload is null'});
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((_err) => {
                        console.log("queryInfo failed with _err = ", _err);
                        res.send({"result": "failed", "message": _err.message});
                    });     
                });
        });
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question about query other business networks (chaincodes) from the existing business network

Comment: The actual code referenced above accesses any business network, not just the one to which hyperledger composer is attached. At the fabric level, you would need access to a valid keyStore, the channel name, the peer request URL and the orderer URL for your target network..